# asp form using javascript return

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, forms

I have an ASP form and I'm using Google geocode to get a lat and long from a postcode. In Internet Explorer the form will submit, but in Google Chrome it won't. It seems to post if I remove `return` from the `OnClientClick="return findLatLng()"`, but then the javascript part won't update the form. I was wondering why I need `return` and what I could do to get around this?

Comment: what value do you return from `findlatlng();`?

Comment: if findlatlng returns true page will postback, if it returns false it wont, return is used to check if we want to proceed with the click event defined in code behind or not.

Comment: please use alert(put your variable here); and second user try catch in  javascript function like that 
try {
//   your function  
} catch(e) {

} 
can you put some js code so we can make it error free

Comment: MSUH could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from MSUH comment, this is whats wrong: if findlatlng returns true page will postback, if it returns false it wont, return is used to check if we want to proceed with the click event defined in code behind or not.